# Articles' titles like "Facebook to buy Whatsapp"

Tags: infinitives

I am new here. I am a Brazilian learning english and I'd like to understand these articles' titles:

**Examples:**

Bethesda *to release* Dishonored 2

Facebook *to buy* Whatsapp

Donald Trump *to build* solar panelled wall on the border

I mean, I can understand them, but when to use this type of sentence construction? For me it seems like something is missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[To + verb in sentence without any other verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209197/to-verb-in-sentence-without-any-other-verb)* Also see *[The form of future implication: to be](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73036)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

News headlines need to be short, so editors rely on certain conventions of interpretation, and you have encountered one such. Generally, the use of an infinitive this way means that a word or phrase such as ***is planning*** or ***has committed*** or ***wants*** has been omitted - thus, ***Facebook to buy WhatsApp*** actually means ***Facebook is going to buy WhatsApp*** or ***Facebook has announced that they are buying WhatsApp*** or ***Facebook intends to buy WhatsApp*** - which it is, if you are uncertain, can be determined from the text of the article.

Comment: Please avoid bloat.